# In datastore, confused on how to pass a list of key_names as an argument to somemodel.get_or_insert()?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Are there examples of how to pass a list of key_names to `Model.get_or_insert()` ?

**My Problem:**

With a method of ParentLayer I want to make the children.

The key_names of the new (or editable) entities of class Child will come from such a list below:

```
namesList = ["picture1","picture2"]
```

so I should be able to build a list of key_names with method from the parent class as follows:

```
class ParentLayer(db.Model):

 def getOrMakeChildren(self, namesList):
            keyslist = [ db.Key.from_path( 'Child' , name , parent = self.key() ) for name in namesList ]
```

the problem is next where I simply want to get_or_insert entities based on `keylist` defined above:

```
            childrenEntitiesList = Child.get_or_insert(keyslist) # no works?
```

also none of the below attempts worked:

```
            #childrenEntitiesList = Child.get_or_insert(keyslist, parent = u'TEST') 
            #childrenEntitiesList = Child.get_or_insert(keyslist, parent=self.key().name() ) 
            #childrenEntitiesList = Child.get_or_insert(keyslist, parent=self.key()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_or_insert` has to use a transaction in order to atomically return or create the requested entity, and you can't execute a single transaction over multiple entities. Also, get_or_insert takes keyword arguments for the constructor, and there's no easy way to specify a different set for each.

If you just want to get_or_insert multiple keys, you could do this:

```
entities = [Child.get_or_insert(k) for k in keylist]
```

As mentioned, this will require a transaction per entity. If you expect that the entities in question will usually exist, an alternative version of get_or_insert may be more useful (and efficient) for you:

```
def _get_or_insert_tx(key, properties):
  """When run in a transaction, fetches or creates an entity atomically."""
  entity = db.get(key)
  if not entity:
    entity = db.class_for_kind(key.kind())(key=key, *properties)
    entity.put()
  return entity

def get_or_insert_multiple(args):
  """Fetches or creates multiple entities.

  Args:
    args: A list of (key, dict-of-properties) tuples
  Returns:
    A list of entities, in the same order as args.
  """
  # First, try and fetch them in a batch, outside the transaction
  entities = db.get([x[0] for x in args])
  # Now, transactionally create or fetch each missing one
  for i in range(len(entities)):
    if entities[i] is None:
      entities[i] = db.run_in_transaction(_get_or_insert_tx, *args[i])
  return entities
```

This code will first attempt to do a batch fetch of all the entities you want to create, and then execute a transaction only for the entities that don't already exist. In the best case, it does a single batch get; in the worst case, it does a batch get followed by a transaction for each entity. Note that, unlike the built in get_or_insert, this one takes keys rather than key names - since that's the syntax you were using.

Here it is in use:

```
entities = get_or_insert_multiple([(k, {}) for k in keys])
```

Note the empty dictionary for each entity, since you're not specifying any properties to be passed to the constructor for new entities.